# No me muestra el codigo que le corresponde a mi lista

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio simple de python, donde tengo 3 listas en las cuales ya tienen valores por default; son codigo, producto y precio.
Lo que intento hacer es que cuando ingrese un nombre el codigo de un producto, me muestre el codigo el nombre del producto y su precio.
Pero de momento no hace lo que le estoy enviando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor edita tu pregunta e introduce tu código como texto, no como imagen. Por otra parte, el `input()` lo tienes adentro del `for` por lo que al imprimir va a imprimir el valor de la iteración actual

Comment: El código debe ir como texto, no como imagen. Por otro lado, está mal planteado el problema, estás solicitando datos al usuario dentro de un `for` que recorre una lista con la descripción de los productos. Lo que debe ser es que primero pides los datos al usuario y luego recorres la lista hasta que lo encuentres (si es que se encuentra). Esto sería más fácil de gestionar con otra estructura, como un diccionario.

Comment: Usas python 2.7? recomiendo subir hasta la 3 si es el caso

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Podrías generar un diccionario con los datos de tus listas utilizando comprensión de diccionarios o un ciclo `for`

Con comprensión de diccionario sería:

```
d = {i:[j, k] for i, j, k in zip(Cod, Produc, precio)}
```

Esto devuelve:

```
{'001': ['Papa', 3.2],
 '002': ['Camote', 3.2],
 '003': ['Quión', 0.5],
 '004': ['Pimentón', 0.5],
 '005': ['Lechuga', 1.5],
 '006': ['Limón', 2.5],
 '007': ['Cebolla', 3.0],
 '008': ['Perejil', 0.2],
 '009': ['Pepinillo', 0.8],
 '010': ['Zanahora', 0.6]}
```

Y para acceder a cada uno de los valores utilizamos las llaves, que serían los códigos del producto y el nombre del producto sería el índice 0 y el precio el índice 1. Por ejemplo, para obtener el precio del Camote

```
d['002'][1]
```

Devuelve:

```
3.2
```

Luego obtienes los datos del cliente, cantidad y el código de producto con `input()` (Tal como lo haces ahora pero sin el `for`)

```
cliente = input('Ingrese el nombre del cliente: ')
cod = input('Producto: ')
cant = float(input('Cantidad (Kg): '))
```

Calculas el sub total, total, igv

```
sub = d[cod][1] * cant
igv = round(sub + 0.18, 2)
total = round(igv + sub, 2)
```

Y produces la salida:

```
print('{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}'.format('Código', 'Producto', 'Precio', 'Cantidad', 'Sub Total', 'IGV', 'Total a pagar'))
print('{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}'.format(cod, d[cod][0], d[cod][1], cant, sub, igv, total))
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
Cod = ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008', '009', '010']
Produc = ['Papa', 'Camote', 'Quión', 'Pimentón', 'Lechuga', 'Limón', 'Cebolla', 'Perejil', 'Pepinillo', 'Zanahora']
precio = [3.20, 3.20, 0.50, 0.50, 1.50, 2.50, 3.00, 0.20, 0.80, 0.60]

d = {i:[j, k] for i, j, k in zip(Cod, Produc, precio)}

cliente = input('Ingrese el nombre del cliente: ')
cod = input('Producto: ')
cant = float(input('Cantidad (Kg): '))

sub = round(d[cod][1] * cant, 2)
igv = round(sub + 0.18, 2)
total = round(igv + sub, 2)

print('{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}'.format('Código', 'Producto', 'Precio', 'Cantidad', 'Sub Total', 'IGV', 'Total a pagar'))
print('{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}{:<15}'.format(cod, d[cod][0], d[cod][1], cant, sub, igv, total))
```

Esto produce:

```
Ingrese el nombre del cliente:  Juan
Producto:  009
Cantidad (Kg):  3.5
Código         Producto       Precio         Cantidad       Sub Total      IGV            Total a pagar  
009            Pepinillo      0.8            3.5            2.8            2.98           5.78
```